# Number of requests = numbers of user

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, performance-testing

I have a question and I appreciate any help.

To make long story short Days ago in a meeting with a qa we talk about the differences between # request and # of users in a case.

I think is different but depends of the case, when I used a service o something like that it doesn't matter, because 1 user perform 10 request in one minute is the same than 10 user perform each 1 request in the same time

But For example if I need to validate the service's throughput send 1000 request in 1 hour, does it matters if I send 1000 request but not from 1000 users in 1 hour?

I want to know other perspective and know other opinions

Thanks in advance for any help

Sorry in advance for the english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make long story short: it depends on the application under test implementation.

Personally I would stick to the following approach: **1 virtual user = 1 real user** with all its stuff (for web applications it would be browser-derived headers, cache, JavaScript-driven calls, handling images, scripts, styles, [caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)), [think times](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-testing-with-a-think-time), etc.)

The idea is to simulate real life usage of the system under test as close as possible where 1 user == 1 producer (or consumer) and then measure the number of requests per second generated by X concurrent users as a part of other performance metrics. See [What is the Relationship Between Users and Hits Per Second?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second) article for more details.

Another important factor is [session](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)), it might be the case the system under test can consider second, third, etc. logins a continuation of the first one or simply don't allow multiple logins.

If you're testing a "stupid" service which doesn't differentiate the incoming requests and doesn't cache the responses it doesn't really matter whether you use 1 thread or 1000 threads as the difference will be only in "sent bytes" metric if credentials have different length (sending 1 request per 3.6 seconds doesn't look like a realistic load test to me in any case)